# Ler xml em VB.net

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

Gostaria de ler a linha `tag` `version="1.0.1.0"` e armazenar em uma variável em Vb.Net?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feed>
  <Tasks>
    <FileUpdateTask hotswap="false" updateTo="file://d:\tmp\update\AtualizadorAplicacao.exe" localPath="AtualizadorAplicacao.exe">
      <Description>Descricao da nova versao.</Description>
      <Conditions>
        <FileVersionCondition what="below" version="1.0.1.0" />
      </Conditions>
    </FileUpdateTask>
  </Tasks>
</Feed>
```

Comment: http://www.macoratti.net/10/08/vbn_xml1.htm

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que o seu XML esteja no arquivo *C:\temp\VBWpfApp1\MeuArquivo.xml*;
Com este código você conseguirá ler o valor do *atributo* `version`:

```
Dim oXML As New XmlDocument

Dim ArquivoXML As String = "C:\temp\VBWpfApp1\MeuArquivo.xml"

oXML.Load(ArquivoXML)        ' Carrega o arquivo XML

Dim oNo = oXML.SelectSingleNode("/Feed/Tasks/FileUpdateTask/Conditions/FileVersionCondition")
Dim versao = oNo.Attributes.GetNamedItem("version").Value
```

Comment: Saudações. @Tony Na segunda linha de código você criou uma variável(ArquivoXML) para poder jogar o arquivo xml através do seu caminho. Você não poderia colocar o caminho entre os parenteses do load? no c# funciona. ex: [oXML.Load("C:\temp\VBWpfApp1\MeuArquivo.xml")]

Comment: Poderia sim, funcionaria também.

Comment: Caso tenha funcionado, por favor +1 e marque como Resposta. :)